# Stopping the io_service after every thread is finished

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-thread

I would like to make the program wait till it finishes all the running threads unlike `ioService.stop();`, which stops the `ioService` without waiting. I tried the following code,which is working fine but stoping the `ioService` without waiting for the threads to finish.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>


void myTask (std::string &str);

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    uint16_t total_threads = 4;

    /*
     * Create an asio::io_service and a thread_group
     */
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    boost::thread_group threadpool;    

    /*
     * This will start the ioService processing loop. 
     */     
    boost::asio::io_service::work work(ioService);

    /*
     * This will add threads to the thread pool.
     */
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < total_threads; ++i)
        threadpool.create_thread(
                boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService));    

    /*
     * This will assign tasks to the thread pool.
     */
    std::string str = "Hello world";
    ioService.post(boost::bind(myTask, std::ref(str) ));



    ioService.stop();

    /*
     * thread pool are finished with
     * their assigned tasks and 'join' them.
     */
    threadpool.join_all();

    return 0;

}


void myTask (std::string &str){
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Compile with : `-lboost_serialization -lboost_thread -lboost_system`

Comment: Stopping a service is not your problem if you don't even get stuff to compile, so you should probably rethink your question. Also, extract a [mcve].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt How is it not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I have given the minimum code which everyone can run and verify the error and other details.

Comment: Can you pack it into one file? Can you remove the lines following the line that caused the error?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have updated my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating `work` as a variable on the stack. `work` tells the io_service that there is still work to be done. From the manual:

> Destructor notifies the io_service that the work is complete.

Since work is created in main on the stack, it's lifetime is longer than you want it to be. It will not be destructed until main exits. Create it on the heap instead, so you can explicitly destroy it. Change it to:

```
using namespace boost::asio;
boost::scoped_ptr<io_service::work> work(new io_service::work(ioService));
```

Then, later, when you want to tell io_service to stop after it has finished all outstanding work, don't stop io_service but destroy 'work' instead, then wait for the thread to finish.

```
work.reset();
threadpool.join_all();
```

This will call `~work()`, which will remove the work object from the io_service. That in turn will cause `io_service::run` to exit when the last pending operation has finished.

A few more notes:

- I would avoid giving a variable the same name as its class. I would't write `io_service::work work(io_service);` It's too confusing. I would write something like `io_service::work some_work(io_service);`
- Be careful with `io_service.post(... std::ref(str));` You are passing a reference to the io_service post action. The variable str must live long enough for the task to finish. I am sure this is here just for the example. In real world applications it can be surprisingly hard to ensure that parameters passed to work objects are not destructed prematurely. I use `shared_ptr<>` a lot or, in cases where that is not possible, I sometimes count the number of outstanding io_service actions with a boost::atomic